# Error: objectdatasource could not find a non-generic method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am binding dropdown list using Object data source. I got an error like this

**"ObjectDataSource 'objDSStatus' could not find a non-generic method 'GetIssueAllowedStatusByCategoryIDStatusIDandUserType' that has parameters: IssueCategoryID."**

My code is as follows

### .aspx

```
< asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" DataSourceID="objDSStatus" 
                                                DataTextField="IssueStatusName" DataValueField="IssueStatusID">                                                

< /asp:DropDownList>
< asp:ObjectDataSource ID="objDSStatus" runat="server" TypeName="DA"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

### .cs

```
private void Bind(int IssueCategoryID, int IssueStatusID, int UserType)  
{  
    ddlStatus.Items.Clear();  
    objDSStatus.SelectMethod = "GetIssueAllowedStatusByCategoryIDStatusIDandUserType";  
    objDSStatus.SelectParameters.Clear();  
    objDSStatus.SelectParameters.Add("IssueCategoryID", IssueCategoryID.ToString());          
    objDSStatus.SelectParameters.Add("IssueStatusID", IssueStatusID.ToString());  
    objDSStatus.SelectParameters.Add("UserType", UserType.ToString());

    objDSStatus.DataBind();  
    ddlStatus.DataBind();  
}
```

### DA.cs

```
public List<IssueStatus> GetIssueAllowedStatusByCategoryIDStatusIDandUserType(int IssueeCategoryID, int IssueStatusID, int UserType)  
{  
    List<IssueStatus> issueStatusList = new List<IssueStatus>();  
}
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks,
Mahesh

Comment: Why did you remove all of my careful editing that fixed all the scrollbars etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't look right to me:

```
objDSStatus.SelectParameters.Add("IssueCategoryID", IssueCategoryID.ToString());
objDSFeedback.SelectParameters.Add("IssueStatusID", IssueStatusID.ToString());
objDSFeedback.SelectParameters.Add("UserType", UserType.ToString());
```

Did you *mean* to add the second and third parameters to `objDSFeedback` instead of `objDSStatus`? Your method has three parameters, after all...

Perhaps you meant this:

```
objDSStatus.SelectParameters.Add("IssueCategoryID", IssueCategoryID.ToString());
objDSStatus.SelectParameters.Add("IssueStatusID", IssueStatusID.ToString());
objDSStatus.SelectParameters.Add("UserType", UserType.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

one of your `DA.cs` parameter is `int IssueeCategoryID` . It should be `int IssueCategoryID`